# Rails reduce image size on some %

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

i need any solution for reducing image size

I am using paperclip

```
has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :small =>{ :geometry =>"200 x 123>"}}
```

For example i have original image 1 Mb and after some magic i want image 300 Kb
and then upload it on aws

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the convert_options

```
has_attached_file :image, 
                  :convert_options => { :thumb => '-quality 50' }
```

or you can try this one

```
has_attached_file :image => { :quality => :better }
```

Refer: [Paperclip doc](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#post-processing)

Comment: has_attached_file :image,:styles =>  {  :thumb => "300x123>" }, :convert_options => { :thumb => '-quality 50' } i did and all ok

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this 
https://github.com/janfoeh/paperclip-optimizer

It's a gem made for image optimization.

If you need a better optimization, use Google PageSpeed module for apache or Nginx !